# when call tabula meets the Error: Cannot create file C:\Users

Tags: python-3.x

the thing is i try to use tabula to read PDF, firstly i use 
tabula.environment_info() to checking my enviroment, it shows fine  like this

then i try to read some pdf

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("./input/CELCOM.pdf")
```

then it seems try to create some file in temp folder,then i meet this

```
Error: Cannot create file C:\Users\C00427~1\AppData\Temp\tmpinxwkue0
Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/04Coding/New folder/test.py", line 206, in <module>
    df = tabula.read_pdf("./input/"+str(each_file), spreadsheet=True, pages=each_tuple[0], multiple_tables=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py", line 150, in read_pdf
    output = _run(java_options, kwargs, path, encoding)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py", line 67, in _run
    return subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', '1', '--lattice', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', '--outfile', 'C:\\Users\\C00427~1\\AppData\\Temp\\tmpinxwkue0', './input/CELCOM.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It seems call java to do something, In fact, this issue comes when this line executed,
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

when I use os.system('java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tabula\tabula-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar --pages 1 --lattice --guess --format JSON --outfile C:\Users\C00427~1\AppData\Temp\tmpbg5u94xu ./input/CELCOM.pdf')

to do this, return 0, so I think its fine, i don't know why Popen have this issue

```
Python version:
    3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Java version:
    java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
tabula-py version: 1.4.0
platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and did some additional troubleshooting.  One interesting point I found was that the temp file is getting created (size 0), but nothing gets written to it.  I tried resolving the issue by setting an environment variable TMPDIR to point to a different location (in case it was a permission issue), but got the same results just with a different output file path.  Also, I ran the java command on the command-line (I'm using windows 10) instead of os.system() and as you found it ran fine.  The only time I get the error is when running from Python.

Answer (score 3):

This was a known issue in tabula-py version 1.4.0, see https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/169 for more details.  I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by upgrading from tabula-py 1.4.0 to 1.4.1 which was just released a few days ago.  Try:

```
pip uninstall tabula-py
pip install tabula-py
```

or whatever method you use to replace libraries in your environment.